# Create category through javascript based outlook-addin

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I want to create email category through java script based outlook-addin, searched through documentation however it seems they have not exposed the api in js.
help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using EWS, it's also possible to create and set categories [using REST from an add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

[Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlookcategory?view=graph-rest-1.0) can be read and set on a [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs). And [master categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-post-mastercategories?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) can be created as well. A benefit of creating the master category first is you can set the color of the category.

The difference between setting the category on the server and using the client-side [JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.item?view=office-js#categories) (currently in preview), is when the category is set on the server, it will not appear right away in the client.

Answer (score 0):

[Office.Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.categories?view=office-js) API Interface is currently in preview. You have the option to wait a while till next release or implement it by sending EWS request via [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext) request and set the category for an item in Exchange.

To set/get categories of the message you may use 2 different message properties ...

1. "Custom" property with Id "00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" ("Keywords") and type of "StringArray"
2. "Field" property with id "item:Categories" ("_Categories"), same type "StringArray".

Please note if category is not on the Master categories List, you still able to set it for the message, but it will have white color.

More information on EWS approach (with XML example) can be found at [How to create/set category to email in OWA add-in](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/0c086a19-de06-4932-8234-860e57cc41cf/how-to-createset-category-to-email-in-owa-addin?forum=appsforoffice).